# LaTeX leaves single line of text above figure

Tags: floats, positioning

Apparently, LaTeX needs some liberty when it comes to figure placement. I've read that `\begin{figure}[htbp]` should be a good starting point for giving it some space to shuffle things around. However, I frequently have a figure placed between two paragraphs. What I expect is:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

[figure]

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi 
ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit 
in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
```

What LaTeX does with `[htbp]` is that it puts the first line of the second paragraph above the figure:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi 

[figure]

ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit 
in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
```

Which looks rather odd to me. So:

1. Why is the figure not simply placed between paragraphs?
2. What can I do to circumvent this, other than bluntly using `[H]`?
3. Or am I maybe the one at fault and is this exactly what it should be doing and I simple lack proper taste in typesetting?
   EDIT: Link to MWE: http://www.filedropper.com/exampletextplacement

Comment: A compileable example would help.

Comment: if you use `[htbp]` then it will first try `h` presumably it would not fit there for example if that point is too low on the page, then next it will try `t` which will put it at the top of the current page which typically will be in an earlier paragraph. But without any example hard to say more.